# Rust generic type implementation for right = |_a| |b| b

Tags: typescript, rust, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, I do:

```
const right = <T>(a: T) => <U>(b: U) => b;

const log = (msg: unknown) =>
  right
    (console.log(msg))
    (msg);

log(1); // 1
log("hello"); // "hello"
log(right(1)(2)); // 2
```

Now, I want to implement the same code in Rust with generic types.

```
let right = |_a| |b| b;

let log = |msg| right(println!("{:?}", msg))(msg);

log(1); // 1   
log("hello"); // compile error  
log(right(1)(2)); // compile error
```

So far, the compile error is like this, and I know why and how the error occurs, and I know this is not a code using generic.

So my question is what would be a proper code to implement this in Rust using generic types to **closure**?

Comment: Aside: your `right` function is a rather obscure way of basically implementing the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator); and in the context of your `log` function, it’d be a lot clearer to just return `msg` after having written to console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to define generic closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814423/possible-to-define-generic-closure)

Comment: @eggyal I disagree to the cleaner aspect. `return` sentence is extra statement and ugly.

Comment: code that is clear and easy to maintain is a million times more beautiful than code that is concise but obscure.

Comment: @eggyal I've checked theQ&A already, and no.

Comment: @eggyal Yeah, I know, but I don't think this short function has such a problem. I maintain my opinion, to use `return` sentence here is ugly, and `right` function is useful in other ways.

Comment: @eggyal, `right` function is clearer and easier than multiple sentences using `return`. Perhaps, you are not a functional programmer. That is the only reason I can think of that you mention your perspective.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your closures are not generic.  They are in fact fixed to a specific type and those types are inferred.  The compiler assigns them once with your first use, and then they don't match for subsequent uses.

If you want to use generic types, it's going to be better to use an explicit function instead of a closure:

```
fn right<T, U>(_x: T) -> impl Fn(U) -> U {
    |b| b
}

fn log<T: std::fmt::Debug>(msg: T) {
    right(println!("{:?}", msg))(msg);
}

fn main() {
    log(1); // 1
    log("hello"); // hello
    log(right(1)(2)); // 2
}
```

Those functions are explicitly generic and appropriately typed, so they'll be monomorphized as appropriate for each instantiation.  If you're unhappy with the increased scope of those functions, you can push them into `main`, and they'll be visible only from there, just like your closures.

Comment: Thanks, but I do know it's not generic, and I thought I mentioned so, and questioned.

Comment: I think `main()` scope doesn't matter much, but what I'm not happy is you said "If you want to use generic types, it's going to be better to use an explicit function instead of a closure:". What is better is that I know, closure, it's a lamda expression. If it's **impossible** to implement generic in closure, please just say so, not the context of better to decide. Thanks.

Comment: @smithK: I think the closest you can get to what you’re asking for is a closure that takes an `&dyn Display` argument.

Comment: @eggyal Well, `right` function is a simple lamda `a->b->b` and I don't think there's a space for other context such as `&Display` comes in.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking about `log`.  However if borrows rather than owned values are acceptable, then for `right` you could consider a closure that takes (and returns) `&dyn Any` which can then subsequently be downcast—but this would then all be dynamic rather than static dispatch, coupled with a higher cognitive load... and I really can’t see the benefit.

Comment: Perhaps a macro would suit you better.  Or indeed, just write `{a; b}` in place of `right(a)(b)`.

Comment: @eggyal So, you suggest in Rust, there's no way to provide generic typed to this simple lambda expression(closure)? Some probably want to imply that from another answer I had already checked, and claim "duplicated question", and the fact is it's never clearly mentioned anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @smithK: in Rust, generics are monomorphized at compile time in order to have static dispatch; however this monomorphization occurs at the function level.  For closures to be generic, monomorphization would have to be possible at the variable level.  To retain static dispatch in this case, you either need to use functions rather than closures (and since your closures aren’t capturing any environment, that’s absolutely fine) as proposed in this answer, or you will have to consider dynamic dispatch such as with `&dyn Any`.

Comment: @eggyal That's pretty informative, thanks. Could you provide a code with `&dyn Any` for my example as your own answer here? I will happily accept it. Thank you.