# Isn't it possible to define closure with generic types?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I'm a functional programmer and try to use Rust in a functional way.

I've read

[Monads and GATs in nightly Rust](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/monads-gats-nightly-rust/)

however, it's disappointing to have seen the code is just to implement Object&Method in the OOP paradigm.

Monads and Functors can be defined in a purely functional way, and what's fundamentally required is Higher-order generic typed functions(people prefer to call HKT or something).

I've also read here

[Possible to define generic closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814423/possible-to-define-generic-closure)

but this is 6 years ago.

Either way, without Higher-order generic typed function, it's impossible to compose Functor or Monad in the standard functional way.

I'm also surprised I can't define a simple identity function properly in the simple lambda expression form.

```
let identity = <T>|a:T| a;
```

It's 2022 now, and is there any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, [no.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/324)

Answer (score 6):

> Isn't it possible to define closure with generic types?

No, as per *2022* and rust *1.58* it is *still* not.

As alternatives:

You can define a function in (almost?) any scope, so as a replacement for `|a:T| -> T { a }`:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn id<T>(a: T) -> T {
        a
    }
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", id(i));    
        println!("{}", id("Foo"));    
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6cc167b4478436b268849681fe7be3f2)

You can also redefine lambdas as per needed (although I would still use a function for it):

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        let id = |a| a;
        println!("{}", id(i));
        let id = |a| a;
        println!("{}", id("Foo"));    
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=830632fa7a3c3458e30630d53952cb2b)